# How can I install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a broken screen?

Tags: system-installation, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have an old laptop with a broken screen that only shows a few things and I considered installing Ubuntu on it. But my second monitor connected via HDMI only appears the fossa image (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), it only appears the installation on the broken screen. What can I do to get the installation to show up on my second monitor?

I specifically want it to appear after the installation process as well, is that possible?

Comment: Really NOT recommended. That said you can disable the internal one in settings > screens or, at least, enable mirror mode instead of the extended desktop you have now. The problem with this workaround is that it only comes to effect after your user logs in.

Comment: Would google the laptop's make and model with replace screen and/or disable internal screen.  Might be a bios setting to disable and only use a second monitor or replacement cost might be cheap enough.

Comment: Depending on what kind of notebook you have, you may be able to use a [Fn] key to disable the broken screen and send only to the external. On a Lenovo, this would be [Fn]+[F7]. Some people call this "presentation mode" ...

Comment: You can do it if you connect a monitor... Or you can replace the screen. That is what I would recommend.